# Android Studio 0.8.1 Proguard file not found

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I am trying to integrate proguard into my project and in the build.gradle I have the following declaration for build type. When I try to compile I get the following error:
       java.io.FileNotFoundException
             /Users/admin/Desktop/enviornment/android/sdks/tools/proguard/proguard-project.txt
 (No such file or directory).

Note: I have also tried "proguard-android.txt" and same error persists. Also I have looked in the 'tools' folder and there is no proguard folder, how can I include it properly and is there another location to point to?

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
```

Comment: This might be the issue : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419

Comment: Since you added a comment I can't mark it as a correct answer. But yeah I figured this out and hadn't gotten around to posting the solution. New SDK install fixed it for me. Also you can manually copy proguard/proguard-android.txt into the tools folder.